# Getting getServerSession from nextjs auth after middleware in API routes

Tags: next.js, middleware, server-side-rendering, next-auth, next.js13

I am using next-auth with nextjs edge functions. I am using the edge to stream data.

I have my middleware

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

// Limit the middleware to paths starting with `/api/`
export const config = {
  matcher: "/api/:function*",
};
```

How do I get access to the session object now in the API route?

As I no longer have access to the normal next req, response, instead it's the Fetch API

```
const handler = async (req: Request): Promise<Response> => {

// Below will fail
const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are passing wrong args to `getServerSession`. this is its type

```
getServerSession<AuthOptions, Session>(...args: GetServerSessionParams<AuthOptions>): Promise<Session | null>
```

I explained authOptions here: [How do I use next auth getServerSession in next js 13 beta server component in app directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75413452/how-do-i-use-next-auth-getserversession-in-next-js-13-beta-server-component-in-a/75909810#75909810)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I pulled this from the docs https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#backend---api-route which is my above implementation (working). When I implement it without the req, res I run into another issue which is flagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259396/invariant-method-expects-to-have-requestasyncstorage-none-available